# Make text content between specified HTML tags toUpperCase in React-Native

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I want to make to uppercase the contents of specific HTML tags with plain JavaScript in a React-Native application.

**Note**: This is a React-Native application. There is no JS `document`, available, nor jQuery. Likewise, CSS `text-transform: uppercase` cannot be used because it will not be displayed in a web browser.

Let's say, there is the following HTML text:

```
<p>This is an <mytag>simple Example</mytag></p>
```

The content of the Tag `<mytag>` shall be transformed to uppercase:

```
<p>This is an <mytag>SIMPLE EXAMPLE</mytag></p>
```

I tried this code:

```
let regEx = storyText.match(/<mytag>(.*?)<\/mytag>/g)
if(regEx) storyText = regEx.map(function(val){
  return val.toUpperCase();
});
```

But the `map()` function returns only the matched content instead of the whole string variable with the transformed part of `<mytag>`.

Also, the `match()` method will return null, if the tag wasn't found. So a fluent programming style like `storyText.match().doSomething` isn't possible.

Since there are more tags to transform, an approach where I can pass variables to the regex-pattern would be appreciated.

Any hints to solve this?

<sub>(This code is used in a React-Native-App with the [`react-native-html-view` Plugin](https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview) which doesn't support `text-transform` out of the box.)</sub>

Comment: _"transform content between Html-Tags to upperCacse"_ , _"But the map-function returns only the matched content instead of the whole string variable with the transformed part of < mytag >."_ Original Question appears to have requirement to set content of `mytag` to uppercase, not tag and content?

Comment: Is requirement to set `<mytag>`  and `<mytag>` text content to uppercase? Can you include text of expected result at Question?

Comment: [Regex, really](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)?

Comment: `react-native-html-view` seems to contain a sophisticated HTML parser. No way you could hook into that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it seems that `document` and DOM manipulation (e.g., i.e., through jQuery and native JS `document` functions) are off limits, I guess you do have to use regex.

Then why not just create a function that does a job like the above: looping through each tag and replacing it via regex?

```
var storyText = "your HTML in a string";
function tagsToUppercase(tags) {
  for(tag in tags) {
    let regex = new RegExp("(<" + tags[tag] + ">)([^<]+)(<\/" + tags[tag] + ">)", "g");
    storyText = storyText.replace(regex, function(match, g1, g2, g3) {
      return g1 + g2.toUpperCase() + g3;
    });
  }
}

// uppercase all <div>, <p>, <span> for example
tagsToUppercase(["div", "p", "span"]);
```

See it working on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/zkr2nu7h/1/).

---

Also, although it probably doesn't apply to this case, <sup><sup><sub><sub><sub>(@Bergi urged me to remind you to)</sub></sub></sub></sup></sup> try to [avoid using regular expressions to manipulate the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not).

Comment: You have implicit globals in your `for` loops.

Comment: "document" isn't supported in a React-Native-Application

Comment: I'm not sure why you stroke through the link that explains why using regex is a bad idea?

Comment: @Bergi Because DOM manipulation isn't possible, I guess I have to use regex and defy the link. Just once. (Sorry.)

Comment: Wait, how would you render HTML without a DOM? And no, even if you don't have access to the DOM it sill is a bad idea to manipulate HTML with Regex, it doesn't invalidate the link.

Comment: @Bergi OP specifies that the HTML will not be rendered in a web browser -- how, I'm not sure. And fine, I'll add the link back in...

Comment: The requirement is just to manipulate the text content between specified tags. It really doesn't matter if regex is a bad idea or not in this case. The task is just a simple text replacement, and it will not be done in a webbrowser

Answer (score 1):

Edit, Updated

> The content of the Tag < mytag > shall be transformed to uppercase:
>
> `<p>This is an <mytag>SIMPLE EXAMPLE</mytag></p>`

You can use `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/(<mytag>)(.*?)(<\/mytag>)/g` to create three capture groups, call `.toUpperCase()` on second capture group

```js
let storyText = "<p>This is an <mytag>simple Example</mytag></p>";
let regEx = storyText.replace(/(<mytag>)(.*?)(<\/mytag>)/g
, function(val, p1, p2, p3) {
  return p1 + p2.toUpperCase() + p3
});

console.log(regEx);
```

Comment: this code ommits the parts before and after the mytag-tag

Comment: The result should be ""<p>This is an <mytag>SIMPLE EXAMPLE</mytag></p>";"

Comment: @itinance _"The result should be ""<p>This is an <mytag>SIMPLE EXAMPLE</mytag></p>";""_ Consider including this description of expected result at Question?

Answer (score 1):

In general you shouldn't be parsing html with javascript. With that in mind, if this is what you truly need to do, then try something like this:

```
let story = '<p>smallcaps</p><h1>heading</h1><div>div</div><p>stuff</p>';
console.log( story.replace(/<(p|span|div)>([^<]*)<\/(p|span|div)>/ig,
    (fullmatch, startag,content,endtag) =>  `<${startag}>${content.toUpperCase()}</${endtag}>` )
)
```

Consider the cases where you might have nested values, `p` inside a `div`, or an `a` or `strong` or `em` inside your `p`. For those cases this doesn't work.

Answer (score -3):

Why not this way ?

```
$("mytag").text($("mytag").text().toUpperCase())
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gub61haL/

Comment: Since it's an react native application, there is no jquery available